# What is the meaning of "40 leagues and 2"?

Tags: archaicisms, measuring-units

League is a widely found but rarely used unit of measurement, measuring roughly "one hour's hike" in many definitions. It tends to mean around 3 miles, or 5 km, in English use.

Tolkien often wrote distances using leagues. For example, Gimli once described one of his journey's distances as *"40 leagues and 2"*.

What does the 2 mean in this case? Is he simply saying *42*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, 42 :-).

It's an example of an [archaism.](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/archaism) Tolkien used them extensively in his writings. As [this Oxford dictionaries blog article](http://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2013/11/archaic-language/) says:

> Whatever Tolkien’s intentions and whatever one thinks of Middle Earth or outmoded expressions, archaic language is fundamental to what he called the sub-creation of this secondary world.

**Digression:**

The combination of **40** with this archaic construction is odd; it's surprising that Tolkien didn't say **two score leagues and two**. This would have been the more typical archaic way of phrasing it. For example, Lincoln began the Gettysburg address with:

> Four score and seven years ago...

and the same format appears extensively in the King James Bible:

> The days of our years are three score and ten

Comment: Tolkien might have written "42 leagues", but that is too moodern. An older formula would have been "40 and two leagues", but he decided for "40 leagues and 2".

Comment: Now, if I were a non-native speaker who had never heard of the [*Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy) and saw the disparity of votes between yours and tchrist's I'd be inclined to think that this answer contains inaccuracies. It doesn't. It's a good, full answer and that is why I am leaving my comment here.

Answer (score 5):

Yep, that’s right: the answer really is just 42. :)

Comment: Not really a good answer, but +1 just because the cultural reference made me smile.

Comment: So, you're saying that Gimli, Aragorn and Legolas' journey is the answer to The Question? ;-)

Comment: Guess we know the question now :)